# Prove that $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B}) = A$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B}) = A$ using a containment proof (that is, prove that each side is a subset of the other side).

I have an idea of how to prove this but I'm not sure how to word it.

Since A intersects with B, it has some of the same elements in B. Since A also intersects with NOT B, A also contains everything not in B. Since A contains the elements both in B and not in B, this expression could simply be written as A.

Comment: You are not guaranteed that either intersection contains anything; they may be empty.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that each side is a subset of the other:

Let $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})$ then either $x \in (A \cap B)$ or $x \in (A \cap \overline{B})$ but in either case $x \in A$.

Let $x \in A$. Now there are $2$ cases:

either $x \in B \implies x \in A \cap B \implies x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})$

or $x \notin B \implies x \in A \cap \overline{B} \implies x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})$

Answer (score 0):

$$(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$$
Distributivity
$$=A\cap(B \cup B^c)$$

$$=A \cap (\mathcal{U})=A$$