# Proving Using Set Identities $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B}) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I was wondering if the following is valid:
$$(A \cap B) \cup(A\cap \overline B) \space \\ \text{Where $\overline B$ is the complement of B.} \\ A \cap(B\cup \overline{B}) \space \text{Distributive law, but in reverse.} \\ A\cap U \space \text{Complement Laws.}\\ A \space \text{Identity Laws.} \space \square$$

Comment: This solution is correct.

Comment: Indeed, that is valid.  Good job!

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957422/prove-that-a-cap-b-cup-a-cap-overlineb-a)

Comment: When you state a set by itself, are you trying to say that our expression $(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap \overline B)$ is equal to that set?

Comment: You could also prove that $(A\cap B) \cup(A\cap\overline B)\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq (A\cap B) \cup(A\cap\overline B)$, though your solution is more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question has an answer, your proof is spot on, using set identities.  Good job!

This can also be proven using "element chasing":

$$x\in [(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})]$$ tells us that $$(x\in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B)$$

$$\iff (x\in A) \land (x\in B\,\lor x\notin B)$$

$$\iff (x\in A) \land \top$$

$$\iff x \in A$$

Hence we get $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \overline{B})= A$.

Comment: Thank you for that other take on this!